# Working with jDeveloper OAF and EBS

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracleapplications, oracle-ebs

I have a new project and need modify a web page in ebusiness suite created with oaf, but dont know where to start.

Just now. I have the jDeveloper with the corresponding patch to oaf framework,
I set the .DBC file in my secure folder to connect to ebs data base and server, but don't know how import the file of the page (and what file) to do the modifications and how deploy these changes.

I know that can sound stupid or without sense but it's my first intrusion with oaf with jdeveloper.

If anyone have a document or some context about this, please let me know.

Best Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1)**Identify BC4J components**-To find appropriate java files to extend the page functionality, Set the profile option FND:Diagnostics to ‘Yes’.  About this page link appears on the bottom of every OA frame work page. Click on this link the page that you want to extend and see all BC4J components behind this OAF page.  Copy the paths and get these .class files from mid-tier $JAVA_TOP .
2)**Get source code**-Import correct java ‘.class’ files as mentioned in above step, use decompilers such as JAD or cavaJ to get original java code from these class files to understand the logic. 
3)**Extend the pages**-Copy to your local system jdeveloper project folders and modify the code and test it from jdeveloper.

4)**Deployment-** Copy the .class files to mid-tier $JAVA_TOP custom directory once tested successfully and use jpximport to substitute the view object extensions. Deploy .class files in binary mode by using winscp or Filezila. If you modify or created new LOV regions(copy these xml files to corresponding application top mds directory in ASCII mode).

5)**Post deployment-** Bounce the mid-tier applications to see changes on page, request DBA to bounce the mid-tier applications(usually developers don’t have privileges to bounce mid-tier applications even in development instance)

Hope this helps, Please let me know if you have any questions.

-Suresh Kandru